# McAfee has cursed my computer to always give me a popup every fifteen minutes with no way to stop it

Tags: windows-10, permissions, anti-virus, uninstall

I reused the hard drive I had on my old computer on my new pc, I forgot the password on it and decided to just used administrator, just a few days ago a McAfee popup decided to show on my computer saying my "trial" was up, this wasn't a virus and I never installed McAfee. I've tried to uninstall it normally but its uninstaller just gives me a white screen, I've tried directly deleting the files but it tells me that access is denied and User "Administrators" has permission for it, even though it isn't actually a user, I've tried changing ownership of the files or giving myself permission to delete them but it always tells me that access is denied. I've tried using McAfee's dedicated uninstaller for McAfee but it always stops in its tracks when trying to delete the folder "mpf" The only other way I could possibly get rid of McAfee that I know of is to buy another subscription and try to uninstall it now that I have access to the application again, and I'm not trying to throw 20 dollars at it just so I can delete it. Please help me.

Comment: Try installing a new trial, then use the dedicated uninstaller again. McAfee often comes pre-bundled on new machines [which is where your 'ghost' might be originally from] & often proves to be a @£$%^ to get rid of. Antiviruses are notoriously difficult to pick out by hand - an essential part of their job, of course, is to be difficult to bypass.

Comment: Additional confusion may be from your definition of 'administrator', which is not a user account with admin perms, it is a dedicated Administrator account. Also 'Administrators' is a group, not a user.

Comment: I am going to guess your computer came with a McAfee already installed.  Have you tried running the McAfee removal tool as an Administrator?  Purchasing another license to McAfee will not solve your problem, since you have a permission problem, activating won't change that fact.

Comment: It's had no result.

Comment: Try to boot in Safe mode to uninstall McAfee. In this mode McAfee won't be running and the files should be accessible for removal.

Comment: Uninstall McAfee and just use W10 defender that is built in.